# Did Ned Flanders murder anyone?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-simpsons

In the last scene of [this gif](http://9gag.com/gag/a4Y2wqw) Ned throws a body out. The end of it is seen here:

[image: Ned tossing body]

What's going on? The rest of the gif shows that he's doing regular stuff, as seen in the full video:

Comment: I heard he was an assassin for the CIA. Maybe that was Mr Rogers

Comment: It's from a non-canon (treehouse) episode, but I don't think this is on topic here? Maybe better on Films&TV,

Comment: It is indeed from [this Treehouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehouse_of_Horror_XXII) parody of *Dexter*. However, this is essentially a link\pic-ID question, which is usually off-topic here.

Comment: I disagree. I don't see this as an ID question. Without the GIF, it'd still be a valid question.

Comment: @Catija Without the gif, there *is* no question... And the gif is in an external site.

Comment: @Walt You don't think that the question "Has Ned Flanders ever killed anyone?" is a question? It's sort of an odd question without the context of the gif, but it's certainly not any more odd than some of the other questions we get.

Comment: @Catija That's the title. But the question's body seems to be about a specific context: What's going on in this scene? Is Ned actually killing someone? So (to me, anyway) it seems we're basically asked to ID a scene from a pic, and the pic is not even here.

Comment: (BTW, if the pic was actually here, I'd still consider it ID but would have much less of a problem with it.)

Comment: @Walt Fixed. :D Just for you!

Comment: He's not doing 'regular stuff' - he's doing things that appear to be murderous - smothering, strangling, splattering blood, stabbing, taping a mouth, until the 'camera' pulls back and shows you it's innocent. Until the final bit, when he appears to be praying but is actually disposing of a dismembered body. Obviously, the humor lies in the surprise reversal.

Comment: This may be somewhat non-sequitur but this video is exactly the kind of humor that I love in the Simpsons

Answer (score 62):

The gif you refer to is from [Treehouse of Horror XXII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehouse_of_Horror_XXII), and in particular the section *Dial D for Diddily*. To quote from the wiki:

> In a parody of Dexter, after hearing who he thinks is God tell him to
>   murder people, Ned Flanders becomes a serial killing vigilante,
>   targeting characters who are Homer's enemies.

Specifically, the gif is a parody of Dexter's opening sequence, which shows Dexter's morning routine in grotesque close-up that alludes to the show's more gory aspects. Dexter cuts himself shaving, we see the blood fill the screen. Dexter cuts ham, we think of his plastic-wrapped victims. Dexter squeezes a blood orange, etc. The Flanders gif flips it. We see a close-up that appears really sinister, then turns out to be totally harmless. That's humorously subverted again in the final clip, which is just gory through and through.

To quote from the wiki on [The Simpsons Treehouse Horror:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Simpsons_Treehouse_of_Horror_episodes)

> These segments usually involve the family in some horror, science
>   fiction, or supernatural setting and always take place outside the
>   normal continuity of the show and are therefore considered to be
>   non-canon.

This is quite obvious given how many non-canon things happen in each of the various Treehouse Horror episodes.

So Flanders murdered someone in a non-canon, supernatural episode, not in the "normal" continuity of the series.

Comment: For the record, the body appears to be that of Barney, who to my knowledge is still very much alive (if most likely heavily inebriated).

Comment: looked like Mayor Quimby to me.

Comment: @Glurth - Maybe?  The messed up hair and googly eyes still makes me think Barney, but I suppose that could be the result of being brutally murdered and stuffed into a garbage bag in several pieces.  Also: necktie, you may be right.  On another note, one thing that doesn't read well in the gif is that Ned appears to be praying in the first frame - a typical Nedly-thing to do - before it zooms out and you realize they're *not his hands*.  It really should pause on that first frame for a bit longer to convey that effect...

Comment: The corpse is wearing a suit and tie, so can't be Barney. I thought Quimby at first, too, but the corpse doesn't have Quimby's distinctive large bulbous nose. I think it's just a generic Springfield resident.